# How to create an ssh tunnel from my PC to a VM in the cloud

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have 2 machines:

1. my local windows PC (for this example X.X.X.X).
2. my cloud VM with public IP (Y.Y.Y.Y).

I have a database on the VM listening to `127.0.0.1:27017`.
I can only connect to my VM using ssh on port `22`.

How can I forward the traffic so that I connect to the database from my PC?
I know I need some tunnel but don't understand how to set it up, should the tunnel be on my PC or on the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had Linux/BSD on a local vm you could use:

```
 ssh username@Y.Y.Y.Y -L 27017:127.0.0.1:22
```

On windows you can use *Cygwin*, or *Linux Subsystem* ([How to install bash on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)) if you are using Windows 10. You can do this with *PuTTY* too, try [this](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html) guide.

Comment: used it like this:

ssh user@remote_host -L 27017:127.0.0.1:27017

this allowed me to connect to localhost at port 27017 and it forward the traffic to my remote host. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

SSH itself makes a tunnel and encrypt data. Try `ssh remotehost -l username` to login remote VM from Linux. There is Putty application in windows too.